# SQLALCHEMY: register handler for 'after_bulk_delete' event in async session

Tags: sqlalchemy, asyncpg

I have a handler func. for User model instances being updated/ deleted via `session.delete()` or via changing user instance attribute and saving it afterwards.

example:

```py
u = await session.get(User, 34)
u.updated_at = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC)
await session.commit()
```

then this handler with 2 events registred works as expected cleaning users cache:

```py
def clear_user_cache(mapper, connection, target):
    task = asyncio.create_task(user_cache.delete_from_cache_by_id(target.id))
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task (weak refs!!!)
    _background_tasks.add(task)
    task.add_done_callback(_background_tasks.discard)
    return task

def register():
    listen(User, 'after_update', clear_user_cache)
    listen(User, 'after_delete', clear_user_cache)
```

events later registered in **lifespan** protocol in **FastApi** and all works correctly but only when User is deleted or updated via it's instance likewise it was shown in the example above.

But i have a function that uses so called bulk_delete:

```py
async def delete_user_by_id(session: 'AsyncSession', user_id: int) -> bool:
    stmt = delete(User).where(User.id == user_id).returning(User.id)
    deleted_id = await session.scalar(stmt)
    await session.commit()
    return bool(deleted_id)
```

and this function does not invoke any of these 2 registered events (after_update or after_delete).

In SQLalchemy docs i have found that there are 'after_bulk_update' event exists https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.SessionEvents.after_bulk_delete but i cant figure out how to properly register it and what use as a target? It does not accept both User or AsyncSession classes. It accepts Sync Session class but does not react on `await session.execute(delete(something))` invocations as well.

```py
def raiser(delete_context):
    print('we are here')
    return 1/0

def register():
    listen(User, 'after_update', clear_user_cache)
    listen(User, 'after_delete', clear_user_cache)
    listen(Session, 'after_bulk_delete', raiser)
```

Question is  - is it possible to intercept User deletion being done via func. `delete_user_by_id` with SqlAlcehemy events (one or another) and how to do it with async session (with asyncpg)?

Thanks.